# How to transform projection EPSG:3857 to EPSG:4326 in java (Geospatial)

Tags: java, geospatial, esri, map-projections, epsg

Is there a way to transform a EPSG:3857 projection to EPSG:4326 in java? I'm using the esri java sdk. I went through the esri skd docs, but couldn't find a way to transform EPSG:3857 to EPSG:4326. Is there a way of doing it?

I have a webMercator like this: `Point property = new Point(1.7040237624799997e7,-3099509.4953500014, SpatialReferences.getWebMercator());`

And have  a WSG84 like this  `Point point1 = new Point(153.089361, -26.802295, SpatialReferences.getWgs84());`

I need to merge them and as those points have different Spatial References I can't display a map property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using the ArcObjects SDK for Java? Then the following code should work because your Point class is implementing the IGeometry interface according to esri java doc

https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/java/api/arcobjects/com/esri/arcgis/geometry/IGeometry.html

```
Point property = new Point(1.7040237624799997e7,-3099509.4953500014, 
                           spatialReferences.getWebMercator());
Point reprojected = property.project(SpatialReferences.getWgs84());
```

Because your Point constructor looks like you're using one of the newer Esri SDKs like ArcGIS Pro SDK or Runtime SDK I'm adding a solution for them too:

```
Point originalPoint = new Point(1.7040237624799997e7,-3099509.4953500014, 
                          spatialReferences.getWebMercator());
Point projectedPoint = (Point) GeometryEngine.project(originalPoint, 
                           SpatialReference.create(4326));
```

according to
https://developers.arcgis.com/java/latest/sample-code/project.htm